# How can I use findstr and/or for loops to select particular columns within a string

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, token, findstr

I have a file (directorylist.txt) that contains the following lines:

141228-0010

141231-0004

150102-0110

150106-0015

150107-0003

150201-0007

The first 6 digits are a date (YYMMDD)

I need a way to list only the lines that match a variable corresponding with the month column MM. For example.. I have a variable %month% that equals 01. I need a file that shows:

150102-0110

150106-0015

150107-0003

I would like to make this happen using a windows batch script. Is there any way to use findstr or for loops? Other options like powershell?

Comment: what about `dir ??01??-*` or `dir ??%month%??-*` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
findstr /r /b "..%month%" directorylist.txt
```

should work for you, if there are no other conditions you've not revealed.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I ended up with: dir /b c:\test | findstr /r /b "..%month%" ... This way I don't need to generate a directorylist.txt file first. Thank you for your speedy help.